# Connection error from Oracle DB - Logstash

Tags: oracle, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

Has anyone faced this issue while connecting to an Oracle DB from Logstash JDBC Input Plugin :

```
[2021-07-22T11:22:42,912][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][9615a4202c23f17db8abee168682c63c25349f105e2579d02086d38fe8145d97] Unable to connect to database. Trying again {:error_message=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond, Authentication lapse 0 ms."}
[2021-07-22T11:22:42,922][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][b9b24f18d4550bc4a001bc364e9e4d369504fce0c99e762583d6da267f2f7e5e] Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond, Authentication lapse 0 ms."}
[2021-07-22T11:22:42,924][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][5d2187e4deef8e15edbd453b49ce621da2d805def7d3a2a1a45abb4b261c5a7f] Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond, Authentication lapse 0 ms."}
[2021-07-22T11:22:42,943][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main][5d2187e4deef8e15edbd453b49ce621da2d805def7d3a2a1a45abb4b261c5a7f] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
    Pipeline_id:main
    Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_user=>"<User>", jdbc_paging_enabled=>true, jdbc_password=><password>, statement=>"select<Fields> from <Table>", jdbc_driver_library=>"<Path>/lib/ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar", jdbc_connection_string=>"jdbc:oracle:thin:@<HOST>:<PORT>:<SID>", id=>"5d2187e4deef8e15edbd453b49ce621da2d805def7d3a2a1a45abb4b261c5a7f", jdbc_driver_class=>"Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", type=>"cis-api-gateway-request", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_00b6436f-afd3-4f1d-8450-d627939f640e", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>"info", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, plugin_timezone=>"utc", last_run_metadata_path=>"<Path>/.logstash_jdbc_last_run", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>"numeric", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true, use_prepared_statements=>false>
    Error: Java::JavaSql::SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    Exception: Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
    Stack: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonIOException(oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CConnection.java:913)
```

I am able to connect with the same credentials and connection details through SQL developer.

Here is my Logstash JDBC Input:

```
jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ORACLE_HOST>:<ORACLE_PORT>:<ORACLE_SID>"
    jdbc_user => "<USER>"
    jdbc_password => "<PASSWORD>"
    jdbc_driver_library => "<PATH>/lib/ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    connection_retry_attempts => 5
    connection_retry_attempts_wait_time => 10
    statement=> "select<Fields> from <Table>"
    type => "<Temp Val>"
  }
```

My Oracle version is 19.3 and Logstash-7.9.1 (windows)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using ojdbc8.jar from oracle jdbc driver 21.1 release. Try a simple standalone java test to connect your db and see if you get same error or not. If the issue reproduce then paste the full error stack trace. SQLDeveloper might be using a different release ojdbc jar.